# can I choose the ads I want to appear in my android app?

Tags: android, admob, ads

if I use admob in my android app.
can I choose the ads that will appear in my app?

I dont want certain topics or products to be advertised in my app, such as (alcohol, adult content, ads from certain countries ... etc )

Comment: I found out how this is done
http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/developer-publisher-controls

Answer (score 2):

There are filter settings on Admob's developer console. Check them out at [Admob's Developer Console.](http://developer.admob.com)

Comment: I cant find the settings that you are talking about, can you post the exact link

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you had found the solution. But I was trying out admob and I found the filter in it.

Follow the following steps:

1. Sign in at www.admob.com
2. Fill up all the bold item (if you have not done so)
3. Select "Sites & Apps" Tab [image: Sites & App]
4. Click on "Add Site/App" (if you have not done so)
5. Click on "Manage Settings  [image: Manage Settings]
6. You will see the Manage Setting Page where you could filter by multiple item [image: Manage Filter Setting Page]

Hope that this step by step will be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for 2015 -

Click Monetize at the Top,

Then click on your app's ad on the left hand side,

Finally click on the Allow & Block tab